# Parallel Manipulation of a Source and destination Array of a Graph

Tags: graph, opencl

I have a source array and a destination array of an MST graph created by placing their ids of the MSTs in place of the actual vertices as follows:

src : 16 16 16 16 16   9   9  9   9   9  9  9   9   9   9 19 19 19 19 19 19 10 10 10 10 10 10 16 16 16 16 16 16   9  9   9   9   9 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19

dest 9   9 10 9  22 10 10 16 16 16 10 10 10 16 19 10 10 13   9 10  9  13 14 19 19 19 19  9  22 29  9   9  9  19 16 19 16 16  9  10  9 10   9 16   9 34

These sources are arranged correspondingly with its destination in the arrays. I want to bring similar pairs at one place. For eg my o/p should look like..

src   16 16 16 16 16 16   9    9   9  9   9

dest   9   9   9   9  9  9  10  10  10 10 10   .... and so on...!
can this be done in parallel, if not in parallel how can this be done sequentially in a performance efficient way..?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to sort (src,dst) pairs with a custom comparison operator. In that case, yes, there are several sort algorithms working efficiently on GPUs. Look for OpenCL/Parallel Bitonic sort and Radix sort.

Comment: I know to sort a single array using bitonic or radix sort, but how to sort pairs...How do I sort with a custom comparison operator...? What does that mean  exactly..?